# Laravel validation issue

Tags: php, laravel, crud, dingo-api

I'm experiencing an issue when validator rules

```
return [
            'features' => 'required|array',
            'features.*' => 'required|string',
            'link' => 'required|url',
            'image' => 'nullable|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,gif,webp|max:2048',
        ];
```

Return me an error that fields are required even if they are present.
[image]
I can't understand what causes the problem. I use identical validation for storing and it works perfectly.

Here is my controller's code

```
public function update(UpdateSite $request, Site $site)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validated();



        if ($validatedData['image']) {
            Storage::delete($site->path);

            $imagePath = $validatedData['image']->store('thumbnails');
            $interventedImage = Image::make(Storage::url($imagePath));
            $interventedImage->resize(500, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
            $interventedImage->save('storage/'.$imagePath);

            $site->update([
                'path' => $imagePath,
            ]);
        }

        $site->update([
            'site_link' => $validatedData['link'],
        ]);

        $site->features()->delete();

        if ($validatedData['features']) {
            foreach ($validatedData['features'] as $feature) {
                $site->features()->save(new SiteFeature(["feature" => $feature]));
            }
        }

        return $this->response->item($site, new SiteTransformer);
    }
```

## Update #1

My route
`$api->put('sites/{id}', 'SiteController@update')->where(['id' => '\d+']);`

Comment: test with json request to see if the issue with the request or the validation

Comment: @Hussein just made a `return var_dump($request->all())` and it appears to be empty. I can't understand where the data is lost

Comment: are you sure about this field name `features[0]` ?

Comment: @Hussein yep. Nonetheless, according to error message `link` is also empty

Comment: can you include the full code for validation and defining rules?

Comment: Make sure your routes are right (method, url...). Because I test your  validator rules, It's totally ok.@Sergey

Comment: I've shown the rules these are validation itself. It's a FormRequest extended Dingo Request

Comment: show form code, suppose passed the form request, no need $request->validated(); , just use $request->input('link') ..etc

Comment: @kenken9999 there is no need in form code since we have the Postman where we send fields and know they will be sent

Comment: in the form request, did you changed return true in `public function authorize()` ?

Comment: @kenken9999 Yes. If I hadn't it would send other error

Comment: Looks like it's a PHP problem connected with PUT/PATCH and form-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in PHP which cannot work with `multipart/form-data` in `PUT`, `PATCH` request. Very curious that this problem is still present since there are in the Internet topics from about 2014.

## Soulution

There is a solution in docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#form-method-spoofing

So to update a record all I need is to use method `post` instead of `put`/`patch` and send an input field `_method = PUT`.

Just tried myself the `put` route was invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I see the api method is `PUT`, but you are using Postman by `form-data` to request. Try to use `x-www-form-urlencoded` request you api.

This is about my test. Sorry for my english.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

if features is an array so line two is correct but if you pass features as a string line two should be remove, this rules say validation that you have two parameter called features one of them is string and is required other also is array and required

```
'features' => 'required|array',
'features.*' => 'required|string',
```